# Android - Pause and Resume thread makes my thread slow

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview, resume, pause

i'm creating a sample game in canvas into a surface view.

I'm using a while with update and draw methods, all working.
Now I'm trying to pause and resume the game. With the methods I found on the internet worked, however when the game is resume it is much slower.

My loop game:

```
    while(playing){  // on runnable thread
       update(); // update all objects of the game
       draw();  //  draw all objects of the game
       control();  // first remove dead objects, after sleep the Thread.
    }
```

And my pause and resume method:

```
    public void pause(){
        playing = false;
        try{
            gameThead.sleep(17);
        } catch(ex){};
    }

    public void resume(){
        playing = true;
        gameThread = new gameThread(this); // this object is a runnable
        gameThread.start();
    }
```

Does anyone know why slow down? And the solution? (Note: I tried to give a fixed sleep instead of a variable, the result is the same slowness)

Thanks.

**@EDIT**

I found the trouble.

My activity had a listener onResume(), and this launch the thread init... But on my construct of surfaceview I do it too... Resuming: When the game is started, have 2 threads... The pause dont do the game too slow, the pause do the game is on right speed... The start game do the game have 2 thread (and 2 updates)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if `playing` is false, there is no need to `sleep` the thread, you could do it like this:

```
// my thread
while(playing && !paused){  // on runnable thread
   update(); // update all objects of the game
   draw();  //  draw all objects of the game
   control();  // first remove dead objects, after sleep the Thread.
}

public void pause(){
    paused = true;
}

public void resume(){
    paused = false;
}

public void quit() {
    playing = false;
}
```

I think your original problem is this code:

```
    gameThread = new gameThread(this); // this object is a runnable
    gameThread.start();
```

each time you are "resuming" the game you are creating a new thread, this could be a memory intensive habit if you expect it to pause a lot (judging by the length of the sleep()). Try keeping 1 single thread around and just toggling the flags.

Comment: I'm not understanding.

Comment: while(playing){
   if(isPaused){
    .... loop game
  }
}


OnPause: isPaused = true;
OnResume: IsPaused = false;